# Why my theme is not working? Reactjs with Material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am learning Material UI and I'm getting used with it. I got a problem with ThemeProvider, the theme that I want, does not show. I imported everything, and created the theme, but I have no ideea where my mistake is.
Here is my code:

```
 import {
makeStyles,
ThemeProvider,
createMuiTheme,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { green, orange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";



const theme = createMuiTheme({
pallete: {
primary: {
  main: orange[500],
},
 },
  });

 function App() {
return 


//here I want to apply it, but it doesn't work
(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <ButtonStyled />
      <TextField //variant="filled"
        color="primary"
        variant="filled"
        // type="date"
        type="email"
        label="Email"
        placeholder="email@email.com"
      />
        <CheckBoxExample />
      <ButtonGroup>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Button
            startIcon={<AddBoxIcon />}
            endIcon={<SaveIcon />}
            
            }}>
            Save
          </Button>
          <Button
            startIcon={<AddBoxIcon />}
            
            }}>
            Discard
          </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ButtonGroup>
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    </header>
  </div>
</ThemeProvider>
);
 }
```

Comment: It's because you've spelt `palette` as `pallete`.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't pay enough attention. Thank you :D